# Xamarin Forms Android Release ViewModel not working

Tags: c#, binding, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, viewmodel

I am developing an app with Xamarin Forms. When I run the app in Debug Mode on device/emulator everything works fine. When I switch on Release Mode ViewModel bindings stop working. The error printed is the following:

> Binding: 'Property' property not found on
>   'MyApp.ViewModel.RegisterViewModel', target property:
>   'Xamarin.Forms.Button.Command'

Anyone had this error?

Comment: could you show us the relevant code ?

Comment: during `Debug` do you happen to get any messages related to binding errors in the `Output-Window` ?

Comment: It happens if I run the app on the device. Running it on the emulator everything works as expected

Comment: Check whether [this discussion](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/37930/binding-testcommand-property-not-found-on-productclas-target-property-xamarin-forms-button) would help you.

Comment: Could you please show your code so maybe we can try to reproduce this issue?

Comment: Posting some code of my app would be useless. All the app was affected by this error. Any bind property is not recognized. However I solved by changing the "Linker Behaviour" setting under the Android Build section, switching it from "Link all assemblies" to "Don't link"  as it was already set in the Debug mode

Comment: @gianis6 what was the cause of that ?